# If rows contain a word, identify and copy all cells from the column and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will look for 4 different words in a row from Sheet ("Project Parts Requisitioning"). Once done, it will copy all cells from that 4 columns and will paste in sheet(GCC) in columns (A,D,E,O).
I have a part of code but it doesn't look for the words, it just simply moves pre-defined cell to those columns.

I would really appreciate if you help me with this one.

```
With Sheets("GCC1") 
    lastrowGCC1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 
End With
arr1 = Array("K", "P", "Q", "AA")
arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O")
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    With Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning")
         lastrow = Application.Max(n, .Cells(.Rows.Count, arr1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
         .Range(.Cells(n, arr1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, arr1(i))).Copy
         Sheets("GCC1").Range(arr2(i) & lastrowGCC1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: "it just simply moves pre-defined cell to those columns" - because that's what your code does, where are you trying to compare the row's cells values with the values ? Your code is not related to what you are describing in your post, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I understand that these four columns have to contain all four words (withour any order), don't they?

Comment: No. For example in first sheet there is:
K  -  Time
P  - Rest
Q  - Sell
AA - Cost
The code should find this words in the row, and copy all their cells from the column and copy them to sheet GCC in column, A,D,E,O. It's should be like an arrangement only with finding function.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub testso()

arr1 = Array("K", "P", "Q", "AA")
arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O")

For i = 0 To 3

    Sheets("GCC").Columns(arr2(i)) = Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning").Cells.Find(arr1(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True).EntireColumn.Value

Next i

End Sub
```